# If else statement not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am using [Meta Box Plugin](https://metabox.io/)

I have two options in Post Edit. One to add a Logo and one to add a Title. On the front end (in my template) I want to show either the Logo or the Title, but not both.
I added this code to my template however it is not working:

```
<?php if( rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', false, 'url') !== '' ) { ?>
    <?php $images = rwmb_meta( 'restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', 'type=image_advanced&size=full' );
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            echo "<img src='{$image['url']}'>"; } ?>
   <?php } else { ?>
            <h1 class="mini-title"><?php echo rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_title' ); ?></h1>
   <?php }  ?>
```

I also tried:

```
<?php if( '' != rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_small_logo' ) ) { ?>
    <?php $images = rwmb_meta( 'restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', 'type=image_advanced&size=full' );
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            echo "<img src='{$image['url']}'>"; } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
           <h1 class="mini-logo"><?php echo rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_title' ); ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>
```

I guess the error is in my if else statement.
Can anyone help?

Thanks so much

Comment: If your if isn't working as expected - what are the values that your code is producing when you check it? What is it supposed to be producing?

Comment: var_dump(rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', false, 'url') );

Comment: This code works by itself:   '<?php $images = rwmb_meta( 'restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', 'type=image_advanced&size=full' );
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            echo "<img src='{$image['url']}'>"; } ?>'    and this code works by itself: '<h1 class="mini-title"><?php echo rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_title' ); ?></h1>'    However it doesn't work when in the if else statement.

Comment: var_dump(rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', false, 'url')) to test what value you're actually checking. That way you can narrow it down to whether the value itself that you're retrieving is not what you're expecting or if there is indeed something wrong with your conditional statement. Also when you say its not working, what is the result your getting? Does it always execute the else block?

Comment: I'm using WordPress. In Page Edit I added two options - 1 to add a Logo and 1 to add a Heading (H1).  Both are working great.   In my page template I can retrieve the values with  no problem with the code:    '<?php $images = rwmb_meta( 'restauranttheme_hero_small_logo', 'type=image_advanced&size=full' );
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
            echo "<img src='{$image['url']}'>"; } ?>'    and    '<h1 class="mini-title"><?php echo rwmb_meta('restauranttheme_hero_title' ); ?></h1>'

Comment: But I don't want to have them both display on the Page. I just want the Logo to display but if the user does not want the Logo to display, then they remove the Logo from Page Edit and the Heading will display on the Page instead.   Perhaps I didn't write the if else statement correctly?  PS - I am a complete newbie to PHP so please excuse my  ignorance. :)